# cannot run command on startup using crontab

Tags: cron, startup

I want to run a command at startup using crontab (or any other alternative but I do not know other alternatives).

I do the following:

1. `crontab -e`
2. `@reboot /usr/bin/ulauncher --hide-window > /dev/null 2>&1 &`
3. I restart and the command did not run (the program did not open).
4. Tried to check `ps -aux | grep -i cron` and the result is `root      1127  0.0  0.0  57036  3280 ?        Ss   17:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f` which means that crontab is not running as the current user, thus I though this is the issue but I am not sure whether it is the issue or not and how to resolve it.

Comment: I think you should tell ulauncher which display to use: try with `env DISPLAY=:0 ` in the command line before `/usr/bin/ulauncher ...`; check the correct value of the DISPLAY environment variable in your particular case. - An alternative is to use the autostart feature: create a desktop file and put it into your autostart directory.

Comment: It should be obvious... but if you want to know *why* a cronjob is failing, **don't** redirect its output and error streams to `/dev/null` - redirect them to a log file that you can examine after

Comment: @steeldriver, that is a redirect to ulauncher output not crontab.